# Local Monticello repository

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, monticello

I would like to run a local Monticello HTTP repository at work, so that we can share code easily among colleagues.

Is there a way to run something similar to SmalltalkHub privately?

**EDIT:**

I have tried all the options here and neither of them seems to work smoothly. Let me recap the options:

1) WebDAV on Apache, following [Stuart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25643865/249001). I have tried it, following some online guides. My current dav.conf looks like this:

```
DavLockDB /tmp/DavLock
Alias /pharo /opt/data/pharo
<Location /pharo>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Options Indexes MultiViews
  Dav On
  AuthType None
</Location>
```

I worked for a few days. Then suddenly I am not able to read new versions of a certain package. Whenever I write a version in an image and read it in another one, I get an exception `ZnInvalidUTF8`. I am not sure why, it may be that WebDAV has issues listing too many files?

2) Setting up my FTP. It seems to work, but when I try to set this repository as a remote in the versionner I get `MCFtpRepository doesNotUnderstnd: #koRemote`

3) SqueakSource3, following [Tobias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25644770/249001). I have tried running the two Gofer commands in both Pharo2 and Pharo3. In Pharo2 it does not load at all. In Pharo3, more or less everything works. I had to fix a few errors due to deprecated or removed messages, but in the end I am able to create projects and write to them.

The problem arises when I read. Apparently SS3 keeps some kind of internal cache. The result is that the list of packages I see on the project page is different from the list of packages that the client gets. The difference seems to be that the client requires a short version of the page, like `http://localhost:8080/ss/MyProject/?C=M;O%3DD`, and the results there are consistently less than in the full page `http://localhost:8080/ss/MyProject`.

Moreover, even on the project page, the list of versions remains cached until I navigate on a different project.

4) SmallTalkHub, following [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25642715/249001). I have tried both using images from the INRIA server and images suggested from the Pharo-VM-loader (they may be the same).

I had to install Seaside again, since there was no ZnZincAdaptor in the downloaded image. I am now able to start SmallTalkHub, but as soon as I try to register a user, I get an error `MessageNotUnderstood: receiver of "new" is nil`. I am not able to track where this error comes from (is there a way to open a server-side debugger instead of returing 500 in Seaside?).

After this error, I can see a user both in mongodb and in the interface, but I am not able to login.

5) Git using filetree, as suggested by [Kylon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652242/249001). This would prevent me from using MetaCello to handle dependencies and looks even more compelx than the other options.

At this point I am at a loss. :-( If I want to use Pharo, I will need to be able to collaborate with my colleagues. Using open source repositories is not an option, at least right now.

> Is there a simple, tried and tested way to set up such a repository?

SqueakSource3 or SmallTalkHub would be even better, thanks to their user interfaces, but I really need at least basic collboration. Having an option that can run on a headless server would also be a big plus, as if this becomes a tool we use, it will not be doable to host the repository on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Sean's answer - if you just want a Metacello repository, and don't necessarily need the full SmalltalkHub stuff, then you just need a WebDav server.  Apache will work fine, and I've even used Confluence's WebDAV support (with some tweaking) successfully in the past.

Comment: actually I incurred in a small issue that looks indebuggable to me. I have been able to use this repo to share code among images for a while. Then, all of a sudden, I am not able to share new versions of a specific package. Every time I load a new version of this package (anything above 8) I get an exception ZnInvalidUTF8. Do you have some suggestions how I can start looking into this?

Comment: Did you set the character set in Apache? Do you have widestrings in your mczs (umlauts in the source?)

Answer (score 2):

Per [this thread](http://forum.world.st/Pharo-dev-Zinc-problem-with-PUT-requests-tp4688705.html) on the Pharo Dev mailing list:

> Setting up the Server:
>
> 1. Download a SmalltalkHub image (https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/SmalltalkHub/)
> 2. Install mongodb on your computer (for Debian: apt-get install mongodb)
> 3. Launch the SmalltalkHub image
> 4. Evaluate: ZnZincServerAdaptor startOn: 8080
> 5. Visit `http://localhost:8080/tools/hub`, create an account and a project

Comment: I am having a problem making this work. In the first place, I cannot find `ZnZincServerAdaptor`. I have tried `ZnServer startOn: 8080` but it just starts a server with a default blank page. Did you try to do this? Maybe it is just something silly, I am a newbie with Smalltalk

Comment: I have made some progress, as I explain in the question. Do you have some more detailed instructions that can help me?

Comment: The ZnZincServerAdaptor is in Zinc-Seaside. The configuration of Smalltalkhub needs fixing

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers:

- Just storing your versions in DropBox work very well!
- You can also install SqueakSource3 (like SmalltalkHub, doesn't need MongoDB):

  ```
  Gofer new
     url:'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/MetacelloConfigurations/main';
     package: 'ConfigurationOfSeaside3';
     load.
  ((Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfSeaside3) project version: #stable) load.
  Gofer new
     url:'http://www.squeaksource.com/MetacelloRepository';
     package: 'ConfigurationOfSqueakSource';
     load.
  ((Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfSqueakSource) project version: #bleedingEdge) load: #('All').
  ```

  Then start your Adaptor (eg `ZnZincServerAdaptor startOn: 8080`) and goto `http://localhost:8080/instalSS`

Comment: Can you suggest me an image to start with? I tried to do this in a clean Pharo3 image, and it more or less works, but whenever I try to actually do anything I get exceptions, method missing and deprecation warnings.

Comment: I have not used this with a Pharo3 image. You can probably start with a [Seaside All-In-One](http://www.seaside.st/distributions/Seaside-3.1-OneClick-Pharo2.zip) which should save you the first 5 lines of my code above.

Comment: The one click image does not start for me (I am using the latest Ubuntu). Still I am able to select many images from the Pharo launcher, and among them there is the Seaside image for Pharo2. I tried to launch it and I get `MessageNotUnderstood: ByteString>>withBlanksTrimmed` as soon as I enter the form on `installSS`. Now, I can quickly fix this as I did in the other image, but I guess I will run into the other issues I list above

Comment: By the way, my main issue is that the list of packages that I get on the page `http://localhost:8080/ss/MyProject/?C=M;O%3DD` (which is what the Monticello client requests) is out of sync with what I see with the web client. Do you have any suggestions where to start looking to fix this? I guess it is some kind of cache, but I cannot find anywhere how to invalidate it (and possibly disable it, the traffic here would be tiny)

Comment: Well there is a cache, yes. There should be a process that runs cache updates periodically. And the cache should be invalidated on every commit. Would you please file a Bug at https://code.google.com/p/squeaksource3/ ?

Comment: I have reported the bug. Hope it helps. In the meantime, I have yet to find a reliable way to share projects with my colleagues... :-(

Comment: Thank you. As a first approach, use a local directory and share it via DropBox or ownCloud. Monticello should work like a charm with that. I try to devote some more time to SqueakSource

Answer (score 0):

Another way is go down the popular route of Git. I am using Github for my projects and it works great while Git itself works very well locally too. So if are already familiar with Git then its a very good choice

You can find more information here https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/PharoForTheEnterprise/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/GitAndPharo/GitAndPharo.pier.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the bad smalltalkhub experience. I have made some fixes to the configuration, and need to check if that is enough

Comment: Thank you! I have loaded the latest image and the latest ConfigurationOfSmalltalkHub (StephanEggermont.16) and now Seaside is installed and I can register just fine. Still, when I try to login, I get `Oops! invalid username or password`. If this helps, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with MongoDB 2.4.9 (although I do not think it is a MongoDB error, since all Mongo tests are green).

Comment: I've asked on the mailing list. On my mac I have the same problem.I have updated the Seaside to #'release3.1', and I probably have missed something. You might want to check if the user is added in Mongo

Comment: Yes, I can see users in Mongo, and they are even listed on the homepage. It is just the login that fails. By the way, I do not know much about seaside, but it would be nice to be able to enable a dev mode where instead of returning error codes (500, 403 and so on) it would open a server side debugger where I could inspect the data and find out what is wrong. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: You are running in deployment mode now. In /config you can change the exception handler for /hub (in filters) from WAErrorHandler to WADebugErrorHandler to get a debugger in your image

Comment: I finally see what is going wrong. It was actually pretty obvious, but anyway is seems there is a path problem. The application is deployed at `/tools/hub`, but it tries to make an AJAX request at `/hub/login/`, getting a 404. Under `config` I see that an Application is deployed under `tools/hub`, while a Dispatcher is deployed under `/hub` and a ShLoginHandler under `/hub/login`. I am not sure what this means, but I cannot access `/hub` directly (403) and it looks like contacting `/tools/hub/login` should be the right thing

Comment: Good catch. That is set in ShRootComponent register (class side)

Comment: Looks like setting it to /hub conflicts with the rest handler though